# Length of a 40MHz antenna

Tags: rf, frequency, antenna, remote-control

A few days ago I had the brilliant idea of replacing the ugly antenna of a 40MHz car remote control with an extendable one. Now the range decreased from 50 meters to 3-4m.

I don't know exactly what I broke so I have some questions, maybe I can fix it:

1. How long exactly the antenna has to be? I broke the original antenna so I cannot measure it exactly, but it was about 37.4cm long (+/-2cm). The problem is that if I divide 7.5m to 1/4 or 1/8 I don't get near the original antenna length?  So, which is the closest 'round' number to 37cm?
2. The wire from the PCB to the new antenna behaves as an antenna and i has to be taken into account. Right?
3. How exact the length should be? Do I loose lot of power if my antenna is 2%-3% longer than it should be?
4. Maybe the problem is not the antenna but something else. For example: the new antenna is longer and goes very close to the PCB (to the quartz crystal). About 1.5-2cm close. Could it influence the correct functioning of the PCB?

---

Update:
I put the antenna back. Still doesn't work. I think accidentally touch and deformed some coils in the receiver.

Comment: Quarter-wavelength is the normal best.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Full wave lenght is 7.5m for 40MHz. Right? Then at 1/4 my antenna would be 1.875m long!! That's too much!

Comment: The original antenna may have been base loaded with an inductor to make it resonate at a shorter length.

Comment: @Andyaka - Actually I see two inductors (SMD) on the PCB. Also the antenna is not connected directly to the PCB but to a 0.3Ohm 'resistor'. But it may well be a coil built as a resistor. Even though the colorful stripes on it makes it look like a resistor.

Comment: Be careful to not exceed legal limits for license free transmitting.

Answer (score 1):

The antenna length of those RC remote is not that critical, almost all RC car antenna is underlength, the underlength antenna is very capacitive so a loading coil/inductor is usually added in series to absorption the capacitive component.

I guess your RC radio is just burnt. buy a new one to continue your test.

Comment: The length is important if the antenna is loaded with a specific inductor and the new length is very different.

Comment: How much will the power (distance) drop if I change the antenna length with few centimeters? I think this is what happen in my case.

Comment: If you don't have a spectrum analyzer, and you want to investigate the antenna length vs distance relationship, you can start with a longer copper wire as antenna (say 500mm), test the range, cut 10mm, test the range, cut 10mm more and test the range, iterate until you find the optimum antenna length.